# How to check if a set of conditions in a string is true in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have an expression:

```
DECLARE @Conditions NVARCHAR(MAX) = '200>100 AND YEAR(GETDATE())=2022'
```

I want to check if the expression is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To execute a string as a SQL statement from within T-SQL, use [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

In your case you'd want to make use of output parameters and embed your code snippet in a larger statement such as `SELECT @outputParam = CASE WHEN <your code snippet> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` *(As T-SQL doesn't have a boolean data type.)*

```
DECLARE @Conditions NVARCHAR(MAX) = '200>100 AND YEAR(GETDATE())=2022';

DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE @SQLResult INT;

SET @SQLString = CONCAT(
    N'SELECT @Result = CASE WHEN ',
    @Conditions,
    N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;'
)

EXECUTE sp_executesql  
    @SQLString  
   ,N'@Result INT OUTPUT'
   ,@Result = @SQLResult OUTPUT;  

-- This SELECT statement returns the value of the OUTPUT parameter.  
SELECT @SQLResult;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5697ea4d14201e44d0e8888abbc6037b

***EDIT:***

Avoiding `CASE` expressions by initialising the result to `0` (fail) and only setting it to `1` (success) if the conditions are true.

```
DECLARE @Conditions NVARCHAR(MAX) = '200>100 AND YEAR(GETDATE())=2022';

DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE @SQLResult INT = 0;

SET @SQLString = CONCAT(
    N'SELECT @Result = 1 WHERE ',
    @Conditions
)

EXECUTE sp_executesql  
    @SQLString  
   ,N'@Result INT OUTPUT'
   ,@Result = @SQLResult OUTPUT;  

-- This SELECT statement returns the value of the OUTPUT parameter.  
SELECT @SQLResult;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3e375c464f1eab2e652bc446a4c7484f

Comment: Just be careful of injection attacks. Imagine if the value was `'1 = 1 THEN 1 END; DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable; --'`.

Comment: @Larnu - Indeed, which is why the linked manual entry specifically states `Important - Run time-compiled Transact-SQL statements can expose applications to malicious attacks.`

Comment: <pedantry>There is a [boolean](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#boolean-data-type) data type (with values TRUE, FALSE and UNKNOWN), but you cannot get a firm grip on one: "Unlike other SQL Server data types, a **Boolean** data type cannot be specified as the data type of a table column or variable, and cannot be returned in a result set."</pedantry>

Comment: @habo And thus the output parameter can't be a boolean. So, yes, pendantry. I like it :)

Comment: @MatBailie you are absolutely right about these types of sql injections but what we can do about it in this case (coding in sql only) ? i think if there is any way to execute this code in complete isolation from every information we solve this problem ! Do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: @AmirHosseinMp02 Simple ; don't do it. Find an alternative solution to your needs that don't require execution of code.